# Get coordinates for specific value on healpy mollview

Tags: python, coordinates, masking, healpy

Is it possible to find the coordinates for a specific value of a hitmap from a **healpy mollview plot**?

For example:
If I have a smoothed out hitmap and want to use the mask:

```
mask = (hitmap > 2.054) & (hitmap < 2.056)
```

to find the required values on of the hitmap.

The hitmap is used to create a mollview plot like this:

```
hp.mollview(hitmap, xsize=2000)
```

Is it then possible to find the coordinates (lon,lat) corresponding to the pixels in the **mollview plot** that satisfy the mask by using the mask?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be via [`hp.pix2ang()`](https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.pixelfunc.pix2ang.html#healpy.pixelfunc.pix2ang):

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as hp

# Get the nside and number of pixels in your map
nside = hp.get_nside(mask)
npix = hp.nside2npix(nside)

# Use pix2ang to get the (l, b) coordinates for each pixel
glons, glats = hp.pix2ang(nside, np.arange(npix), lonlat=True)
```

This will give you a list of all the coordinates (l, b) for each pixel in your map. To get only the ones in the mask, simply use:

```
glons_eff = glons[mask]
glats_eff = glats[mask]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this a good way of overplotting the mollview plot with another plot? For example using:

    hp.projplot(glons_eff,glats_eff, lonlat=True)

I tried using 

    healpy.projaxes.CartesianAxes.contour()

to plot a contour at the value 2.055 (between the two values in the mask) But this does not seem to work for me...

Comment: There is currently no built-in function to draw contours in healpy, the function you're referring to does not exist in the latest healpy version.